# Rand() function in C for random ASCII - character (letters and numbers only)

Tags: c, random

I know how to create random values with the rand() function in C with just one specific min and max value. 
Now I want to code a program with multiple min and max values, because my return value is supposed to be a random ASCII - character, but only letters and digits, and I am kind of stuck here.
Could someone give me a hint how to solve this?
Thank you!

Comment: Who says the random numbers you generate must be the character codes themselves?  Just map the characters you want to generate to a contiguous range of numbers.  For example, put them all in an array, and generate random indexes into that array.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  It would be good if you showed your code to manage a single 'min and max value'.  However, it is probably easiest to decide that 'a-z' are the values 0..25; that 'A-Z' are the values 26..51, and '0-9' are the values 52..61.  You choose a value at random from the range [0..62) (62 possible values between 0 and 61) and then map the result into the character of choice  If you have an array or string with the 62 possible characters in it, you can index into that array with the random value between 0 and 61 inclusive.

Comment: Thank you, still working on it, but at least I have something to work with now!

Comment: If you want to answer your own question, post an answer; don't edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

this will output random characters from one of the intervals in ranges[][], the function starts by generating a random value less or equal to the sum of all ranges, then it goes over those ranges to see in which one the value falls in.

For example, with {{10,20}, {25, 29}}, when the random is 0 it gets mapped to 10 from {10, 20}, 11 to 25 from {25, 29}, 12 to 26, etc..

```
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdarg.h>
# include <sys/time.h>

# define LEN(X) (sizeof (X) / sizeof (X)[0])

void
putrandomchar(void)
{
    const char ranges[][2] = {{'0', '9'}, {'A', 'Z'}, {'a', 'z'}};

    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < LEN(ranges); i++)
        max += ranges[i][1] - ranges[i][0] + 1;

    char n = random() % max;
    for (int i = 0; i < LEN(ranges); i++) {
        int L = ranges[i][1] - ranges[i][0] + 1;
        if (n < L) {
            putchar(n + ranges[i][0]);
            break;
        }
        n -= L;
    }
}

int
main(void)
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv,NULL);
    srandom((time_t)tv.tv_usec);
    for (;;)
        putrandomchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to code a program with multiple min and max values, because my return value is supposed to be a random ASCII - character, but only numbers and digits, and I am kind of stuck here.

**NOTE: When you say "numbers and digits" I'm assuming you meant to say "letters and digits".**

There are 26 letters and 10 digits, which is 36 possibilities, so generate a random number from 0 to 35. To get a random number from 0 to 35 (without causing "modulo bias"), try:

```
    do {
        v = rand() & 63;
    } while(v > 35);
```

If the number is less than 10, add '0' to it to convert it to an ASCII digit. Otherwise, subtract 10 and add 'A' to it to convert it to an ASCII letter.

The end result might be:

```
    do {
        v = rand() & 63;
    } while(v > 35);
    if(v < 10) {
        return v + '0';
    }
    return v - 10 + 'A';
```

Answer (score 0):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define UNTER 0
#define OBER 61
#define MAX 70

int rand_sign(unsigned short u, unsigned short o);

int main (void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char a = '0';
    char b = 'A';
    char c = 'a';
    char ascii[MAX];

    for(i = 0; a <= '9'; i++, c++){
        ascii[i] = a;
    }
    for(i = 10; b <= 'Z'; i++, c++){
        ascii[i] = c;
    }
    for(i = 36; c <= 'z'; i++, c++){
        ascii[i] = c;
    }
    printf("%c", ascii[10]);


    srand(time(NULL));
    j = rand_sign(UNTER, OBER);
    printf("%c", ascii[j]);
    return 0;
}

int rand_sign(unsigned short u, unsigned short o)
{
    if(u > o){
        return(rand() % (u + 1 - o) + o);
    }else{
    return(rand() % (o + 1 - u) + u);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't simply map all the characters you want to an array?

```
double rrandom()
{
    return (double)rand() / (double)(RAND_MAX + 1);
}

int rand_int(int min, int max)
{
    return (int)floor(rrandom() * ((double)max - (double)min + 1.0) + (double)min);
}

char rand_alpha()
{
    const char alpha[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
                          'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j',
                          'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't',
                          'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D',
                          'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N',
                          'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X',
                          'Y', 'Z'};
    return alpha[rand_int(0, 61)];
}
```

Be sure to include `math.h` for the `floor` function.